# How to compress an image until a fixed byte size is reached

Tags: java, android

I have an application that needs to communicate with a server exchanging images via their Base64 representation. Due to server capacity, I can only compress and send images that are < 100KB of size. I can easily retrieve the size of the image using:

```
File file= new File(path);
long size = file.length() / 1024;  // KB
```

and that displays the exact size. Then I decode it into a Bitmap and compress it using:

```
int quality= 100;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, baos);
byte[] byteArr = baos.toByteArray();
```

And here things get dirty. I can't properly retrieve the exact size value as I did before, because if the size is > 100KB then I need to re-compress it adjusting the quality.

**EDIT**: forgot to mention that I have tried `byte.length` method but the resulting size isn't the same as it was before.
In this example, I have tried with an 80KB image, as shown in the AndroidStudio Console:
[image]

Comment: "I can't properly retrieve the exact size value as I did before" -- `size` has not changed, as you have not modified the contents of `file`. "then I need to re-compress it adjusting the quality" -- so, check the length of `byteArr` and see if it is over your limit.

Comment: "the resulting size isn't the same as it was before" -- you divided `file.length()` by `1024`. You do not show how you compute `sizeAfterCompress`, but perhaps you did not divide the value by `1024`. Or, perhaps you could skip dividing `file.length()` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [this](https://github.com/shaohui10086/AdvancedLuban) library which accepts Max-Size (in kb) for compression.
Example (From readme.md):

```
   Luban.compress(context, file)
            .setMaxSize(100)                // limit the final image size（unit：Kb）
            .setMaxHeight(1920)             // limit image height
            .setMaxWidth(1080)              // limit image width
            .putGear(Luban.CUSTOM_GEAR)     // use CUSTOM GEAR compression mode
            .asObservable()
```

However i strongly suggest you to not send binary data (such as images) as Base64 since it'll reduce performance and increase size!
It's better to upload it in binary.

If none of above solutions suits you, then at least try to implement your method using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over your compression section, reducing the value of `quality` each loop until the desired size is reached. You can check the size by evaluating `byteArr.length`

Comment: forgot to say that I already tried this way, posted an edit, hope it can be helpful